# Making a normal factory as windsor typed factory

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have my `Factory` which should be called all the time I want an `IValidationProgram`

```
public static class Factory{
  public static IValidationProgram CreateProgramA(){
    var program = new ValidationProgram(
       new DependencyA(
         new SubDependencyA(),
         new SubDependencyB(),
       ),
       new DependencyB()
    );
  }
}
```

I wanted to Register like that:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<IValidationProgram>().Instance(Factory.CreateProgramA()).LifeStyleTransient());
```

But I do not get an new instance all the time when `IValidationProgram` is resolved. I read that I need a typed Factory, but I tried for 2 days without success for my case. All these Dependencies and Subdependencies have an Interface. But I THINK I dont need them for that. If they may help lets name them `IDependency` and `ISubDependency`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get a new instance because you supply, during the registration, the instance already created instead of let the container create it(suggested behaviour...). IOW: since you use "Instance" during the registration, the specified lifestyle will be simply ignored.

The usual registration should be:

```
Component.For<IValidationProgram>().ImplementedBy<yourValidationProgram>.LifeStyleTransient()
```

if you really need a factory for you component you may used a  [TypedFactory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx?HL=typedfactory) or the inline registration UsingFactoryMethod

```
container
  .Register(
   Component.For<IValidationProgramFactory>().ImplementedBy<YourValidationProgramFactory>(),
   Component.For<IValidationProgram>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<IValidationProgramFactory>().Create())
  );
```

In that case you may use your instance approach but for the factory only!

```
   Component.For<IValidationProgramFactory>().Instance(new Factory())
```